# Why did Mike say "You know we only put one guy outside the service elevator"?

Tags: dialogue, angel-has-fallen

In *Angel Has Fallen* (2019), disguised Mike used his old mate as a human shield in the service elevator in order to make his way to the hospital where President Trumbull was:

> Billy: What the f*ck?
>
> Mike: Sorry, Billy. **You know we only put one guy outside the service
>   elevator**. Go on. Turn around.

Why did Mike say, "You know we only put one guy outside the service elevator"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike is pointing out to Billy that he knows Billy has no backup at that location, as the standard protocol is only to have one agent on the service elevator. Mike has him cold.

It's a way to try and ensure that Billy, who currently believes Mike tried to kill the President for the Russians, cooperates with Mike's intentions without causing a ruckus.